# Android: Getting notified when a screen capture is done

Tags: android, screenshot, capture

Is there any way to get notified when a screen capture is performed using the soft key or the device hard key on android? Any way that works 2.3 onwards will help greatly.

**Use case:**

I already block screen capture using `FLAG_SECURE`. I want to show a `Custom Dialog` to the user when this action is performed. Android supplied mechanisms vary. Sometimes a notification is seen while at others, a blank screenshot is captured with no user feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to get notified when a screen capture is performed using the soft key or the device hard key on android?

No, sorry.